# Finding the Exact Offset value of a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I have a HTML page with many divs. I want to find the particular unique value of each and every Div everytime.

Offset values are changing everytime I refresh the page. Is there any method which allows me to do that?

Comment: at what `unique value` are you referring to ?

Comment: I want to trigger the hover function to the left every time it reaches the end of the div. For that I need to find the unique offset value to trigger it perfectly as I want

Comment: you got a lot of answers telling you how to get the offset of all `divs`. isn't that what you want ?

Comment: No.. I want the unique value of a each and every position in a html page.. Dont know whether it is possible..

Comment: you can do that but you will have a list of numbers that don't say much. Not sure why you want that. For example open your console here in SO and [use the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/7kEGD/). You will get a lot of values that you can store somewhere. It may be helpful if you described your problem more or even make a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).offset());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').each(function() { console.log($(this).offset()); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the offset values change on every page load because they are being read when the page is not yet fully loaded.
try wrapping them in a $(window).load(function{}) thingy

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('div').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).offset());
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div').each(function() {
  /* no need to pass through jQuery function to retrieve offset */
  console.log(this.offsetLeft + " - " + this.offsetTop); 
});
```

Comment: :facepalm:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.

Comment: 1) I don't see any requirement in OP question about IE6. 2) Polyfills exist 3) please don't be rude. You just made a wrong assertion about the unexistence of forEach